# Should i use multiple services file in angular 5 or just 1 file for all the functions?

Tags: angular

I have multiple API's for different components, so what should I prefer to do, whether putting all the functions in one service or should I create multiple services. Example-component 1 uses 4 particular functions out of 10 total functions. should I create 1 service for 10 functions or two different services consists of 4 and 6 functions respectively

Comment: Better to keep your services separate by functionality. And you can access your services from different components.

Comment: refer : https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#single-responsibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this : [**Angular Style Guide by Angular.io**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#single-responsibility)

You should follow [**SOLID**](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2015/07/solid-principle-in-detail.html) principles , and for your case follow **Single Responsibility principle**

you class should targeted to do single function i.e. single responsiblity , which says that you should not mix all your code i.e. resposiblity in one class

**Example** : customer class handle customer related activity it should not handle user related activity

If you are adding all method which are not related then you are putting too many responsibility to one class. To avoid that you should separate responsibility by creating classes which have related methods only in it.

Answer (score 7):

It all depends on you'r strategy, you should always consider future of your app and think about all the possibilities. Here is my logic in my apps.

Generally I use one specific service for each module for example if we want to have a website for the university we have

1. Student.module
2. Class.module

Each module have components and one service and for each service we will have four general actions i.e.

1. `Add`
2. `Edit`
3. `Delete`
4. `List`

So I will have Services in the following addresses:

1. `App/class/class.service.ts`
2. `App/student/student.service.ts`

The other logic is to create a folder called service in the app-root and place all the services in it. ( **which is not recommended** ) which is structured as below

1. `app/service/class.service.ts`
2. `app/service/class.service.ts`

The worst logic is to create one file known as service.ts in the app-root and paste all the service codes in it ( **never recommend at all** )

Comment: Im new in angular 5 ,but in angularJS i had a single file (services) in which i used to put my all service file. Why this practice is not recommended in angualr 5

Comment: You better to gave separete services , because you can debug your app better as long as app will go bigger.

Comment: I agree with this. It's better to create a module with its own component, view, service and model specifically for that purpose. As for option #1, I would use CRUD method (Create, Read, Update, Delete). 
Its (in my opinion) a bad practice to store all services in one service folder or have all services in one file.

Answer (score 2):

For deciding the architecture of Angular for service files, you need to keep below points in mind:

- Module (feature) specific files should be kept in separate module. Your code should have high cohesion
- If there are common service files that are required by different modules, then create a shared module and put all `common.svc.ts` files in it. Reason being, you can reuse the service for all the modules.
- While creating service files in `shared` module, try to break it down further depending on the the features which they provide. This will break your long service files into meaningful small files which are easier to maintain.
- You can also create one `common.svc` file which itself doesn't have any business logic, rather it provides access of all the common services. The importance of this `common.svc` will be that you won't have to inject all the `shared` services inside `components`. You can have access of all `shared` service by just injecting this `common.svc` file. It'll act as a gateway to access all the `shared` services. So now you can have access of, let's say **5** `shared` services by just injecting **1** `common.svc` inside a component.

Do let me know if you need more clarification for any of the above points.

You can refer **SOLID design principal** to have a better code irrespective of your language

Comment: its angualr or javascript or c# you must follow SOLID principless, it not about decision its about practise

Comment: you havent wrote single line about SOLID, I think its better to point in right direction , if he read SOLID he will get his answer and follow same in his next project ...

Comment: what is meaning of overdo , its about following pattern and getting it right , just giving answer it not enough some time , pointing some one in direction where he/she can follow for life time and getting information that is need it also important